# Problem upload image

Tags: image, image-upload

I have installed a new magento store.

I upload the image but, when i rollover the image, the image missing.

I have see into directory:

/media/catalog/product/p/r/prodotto-prova-1_6.jpg

the image exists but from the browser missing.
http://my-domain.com/media/catalog/product/p/r/prodotto-prova-1_6.jpg
the image missing[image]
[image]

Why?

Thanks
Ale

Comment: look in the media folder on the server via ftp or ssh, make sure the file doesn't exist in the file path.

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions of your media folder and make sure it is writeable.

Comment: already Done but the problem remains

Comment: Also make sure any subfolders are writeable.

Comment: the dir media and subdir are writeable.

the image is present in 
/media/catalog/product/p/r/prodotto-prova-1_6.jpg

but if i write

http://mydomain/media/catalog/product/p/r/prodotto-prova-1_6.jpg

the image not exist

Comment: missing all image.

Comment: If the image exists in the folder, but you can't pull it up via the url, it sounds like you have a rewrite causing you issues.   Check your .htaccess file.